# can not join on multiple condition between two dataframes

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to applicate jointure between two dataframes.

```
df_temp_5=df_temp_4 \
    .join(df_position_g, cond, "left")
```

Where

```
cond1=df_position_g.position_pk==df_keys_position_g.position_pk
cond2=df_position_g.dt_deb_val==df_keys_position_g.max_dt
cond = [cond1 & cond2]
```

and

```
df_temp_4 =df_key_hub_instrument\
        .join(df_lnk_position,["instrument_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_key_hub_portefeuille,["portefeuille_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_lnk_tiers_instrument,["instrument_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_keys_position_hors_bilan,["position_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_keys_portefeuille_sigma,["portefeuille_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_keys_instrument_sigma,["instrument_pk"], "outer") \
        .join(df_keys_cotation_sigma,["instrument_pk"], "outer")
```

Note that **df_temp_4** is fine and there is no problem there .
But, I have issue when trying to join with **df_temp_5**

As an error :

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o466.join. :
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s)
> max_dt#238 missing from valeur_actuelle#88,montant_coupon_couru_acha

Any help, please ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to join `df_temp_4` with `df_position_g` but the join `cond` mentions `df_keys_position_g` and `df_position_g`. This seems to be a mistake.

Also, `cond1` and `cond2` must have brackets around them because the operator precedence of `&` is [higher](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`.

```py
# This will work as expected
cond1=(df_position_g.position_pk==df_keys_position_g.position_pk)
cond2=(df_position_g.dt_deb_val==df_keys_position_g.max_dt)
cond = [cond1 & cond2]
```

Alternatively, avoid brackets if `&` is not mentioned explicitly.

```py
# This will also work as expected
cond1=df_position_g.position_pk==df_keys_position_g.position_pk
cond2=df_position_g.dt_deb_val==df_keys_position_g.max_dt
cond = [cond1, cond2]
```

Finally, based on the error message shared it looks like there is more than one column called `max_dt` in `df_position_g`, hence it cannot identify the right column. It could also be due to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14948) spark bug. So try renaming the columns used in the join condition just to be safe.

```py
df_keys_position_g = df_keys_position_g.withColumnRenamed("position_pk", "keys_position_pk")\
                       .withColumnRenamed("max_dt", "keys_position_max_dt")
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
cond = cond1 & cond2
```

Instead of

```
cond = [cond1 & cond2]
```

This is because writing `cond` with brackets will treat it as a list.

Answer (score 0):

looking at this, source code of [DataFrame.join](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.join)

```
>>> cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age]
>>> df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
[Row(name='Alice', age=2), Row(name='Bob', age=5)]
```